# SetValue Method throw Exception when using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to set value to properties in many objects.
I've a function that receive 2 parameters MyStructuredObjects and MyObject
MyStructuredObjects has a list of MyObjects.
This Function is a re-factory to remove a lot of 'if's.

I'd like to use ever the same object because the function it is used in a loop.If it is possible. 
I've getting ever the exception 'Object does not match target'.
Sorry posting this, but I don't found problems like this, using List inside a Object structure.

Take a look :

```
public class MyStructuredObjects
{
    public List<MyObject1> Object1 { get; set; }
    public List<MyObject2> Object2 { get; set; }
    public List<MyObject3> Object3 { get; set; }
    public List<MyObject4> Object4 { get; set; }
    public List<MyObject5> Object5 { get; set; }
}

private void SetValuesToObjectsToIntegrate<T>(ref MyStructuredObjects returnedObject, T obj)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    var propertyInfo = new ObjectsToIntegrate().GetType().GetProperties();
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    foreach (var item in returnedObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var itemType = item.PropertyType;
        if (t == itemType)      // PASSING BY HERE OK , it finds the same type :P
        {
            item.SetValue(t, Convert.ChangeType(obj, item.PropertyType), null);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update: The code should be:

```
item.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(obj, item.PropertyType), null);
```

Comment: `SetValue` expects an *instance*. You're just passing it the type. You probably want to use `item.SetValue(returnedObject...`

Comment: Hi Rob, change to `code
      item.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(obj, item.PropertyType), null); `
But doesn't work.

Comment: @Summerson - Please don't edit your question to invalidate the comments. History is important when trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.

It appears that you're trying to set properties like this:

```
var o2 = new List<MyObject2>();
var mso = new MyStructuredObjects();
SetValuesToObjectsToIntegrate(ref mso, o2);
```

So that `mso` will have its property `Object2` set because the type of `o2` matches the property type.

If that's the case, then you only need this code:

```
private void SetValuesToObjectsToIntegrate<T>(MyStructuredObjects returnedObject, T obj)
{
    foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(MyStructuredObjects).GetProperties())
    {
        if (typeof(T) == propertyInfo.PropertyType)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(returnedObject, obj, null);
        }
    }
}
```

There's no need to pass `MyStructuredObjects returnedObject` by `ref` as you're not changing the instance of `returnedObject`.

Use this to call this code:

```
var o2 = new List<MyObject2>();
var mso = new MyStructuredObjects();
SetValuesToObjectsToIntegrate(mso, o2);
```

After this call I now get:

[image: result]